# Generate row, after input send data to php through href using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to create a table that can add a new row when click a button or link, and then let user input and submit the value to php and store it in database.

Problem 1:

In my HTML,

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML +=
    "<td><textarea id='addRow' name='addRow'></textarea></td>";

    var addRow = document.getElementById('addRow').innerHTML;     <-- Is this correct? Because I'm unable to get the data, tried with .value and .innerHTML.

    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML +=
    "<td><a href='page2.php?addRow=" + addRow + "'>Add</a></td>";
</script>
```

It's work fine when I add a row, by when I press the `Add` generated by the script, it's didn't obtain the value I input into the textarea.

Problem 2 :

The link generated from the javascript, when it is clicked, it submit an address like this :

```
page2.php?addRow=
```

The address consists of empty data, but it should be save in the `page2.php` too because I do not set any checking for the value.

Here is my `page2.php` code :

```
<?php
    require("Connections/localhost.php");

    $addRow = $_REQUEST["addRow"];          <-- I tried with $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST.
    $query = "INSERT INTO row2 (addRow) VALUES ($addRow)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    header("Location:Home.php");

?>
```

What is the error of my code?

EDIT :

(12/11/2012) I have uploaded my code to [here](http://anonynewbie.site11.com/IMS/Home.html). How can I solve this problem?

(17/11/2012) The MySQL part, there is some syntax error I made, that is I forget to put the single quote `' '` for each VALUES.

Solved :

I change the `href` to another javascript function.

```
"<td><h4><a href='javascript:send()'>Add</a></h4></td>"
```

In the `send()`, I get the textarea value and submit it with `window.location()`. That's solve my problem.

May be my code is not the appropriate way to do it, but I'll try to improve next time.

Comment: I bet you have multiple rows with the same ID don't you? Also, that is some sexy SQL Injection vulnerable code you got there.

Comment: Please, put down the deprecated `mysql_query` function and step away from it slowly. You're going to cause yourself some *severe* harm if you stay on this reckless path. You must always employ [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) when writing queries. New applications should use PDO or `mysqli`.

Comment: Since you're just getting started, you might want to try one of the popular PHP frameworks like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) to give your application some structure and a lot more capability than you could create from the ground up like you're trying to do here. Code like what you've created here is a sterling example of why frameworks are essential to creating reliable applications and being productive as a programmer implementing your specific logic and not wasting time on already solved problems.

Comment: @Chad, the id `addRow` only declared once, which is in the script. By the way, what do you meant by `some sexy SQL Injection`? @@
@tadman, yes, I'm just getting started, and the SQL code I'm refer to my reference book and my lecturer's note.

Comment: If your lecturer is teaching you `mysql_query` you're learning an obsolete interface from the 1990s. Considering [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) only takes a half hour to learn, this is inexcusable. Please read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) to see how dangerous this kind of code is. Also, for your own sake, pick a framework and learn it well. You'll be massively more productive.

Comment: @tadman, ok, let's the SQL part aside first, how is my script there? Why cannot retrieve the value? And to obtain the value from the address in the `php`, which is correct to use? `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: This would be a lot easier with jQuery where what you want is `$('#addRow').val()` but in your case `document.getElementById('addRow').value` should do the job. You may have another element with that ID which conflicts, though. What you're doing here, though, runs against many of the simple principles of proper application design. If you can get that element correctly set in your query string, then `$_GET` should have the right value.

Comment: I'll give it a try first. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: Still not working. I uploaded my code to free hosting. Can you have a look at it? @tadman

Comment: What is posting the values to your PHP script? Where is the javascript that does the ajax (or the form that is posting)?

Comment: @Chad, this page I used to view a news, I'm doing it for administration part, meaning that admin login. I'm not using any ajax and jquery, because I'm not stick to them yet. The data I want to send through address to a PHP that will do the SQL part. I can simply solve this by creating another PHP page with form, but I want to try something else like using javascript to post the data.

Comment: So is your question how to submit the data via ajax, then pick it up and use it on your php page?

Comment: Can consider something like that. My purpose is to use javascript create an textarea, let user input, and submit data through href generated using javascript, and then pick it up and use it to inject into database.